# WKRefreshBackgroundTask Error attempting to reach file bktasksnapshot_(null)

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos-4

When executing a background task in watchOS 4.0 (Xcode 9.0 beta 6) I get error messages similar to below.  They don't appear to be causing any issues, but I'm not sure.  Does anyone know what is causing these errors to get logged and if there is a fix or a way to suppress them?

> 2017-08-24 09:03:40.130009-0400 cfanow Watch App Extension[6906:377766] [bg_app_refresh] -[WKRefreshBackgroundTask cleanupStorage]_block_invoke:213: Error attempting to reach file:///Users/justindomnitz/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/264AA014-FD6C-426A-88DF-64E502393BAF/data/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/107681EE-B30E-49CD-9416-8F030D1CA0BF/Library/com.apple.watchkit/bktasksnapshot_(null): Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “bktasksnapshot_(null)” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/justindomnitz/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/264AA014-FD6C-426A-88DF-64E502393BAF/data/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/107681EE-B30E-49CD-9416-8F030D1CA0BF/Library/com.apple.watchkit/bktasksnapshot_(null), NSFilePath=/Users/justindomnitz/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/264AA014-FD6C-426A-88DF-64E502393BAF/data/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/107681EE-B30E-49CD-9416-8F030D1CA0BF/Library/com.apple.watchkit/bktasksnapshot_(null), NSUnderlyingError=0x79f3f3c0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Comment: Have you tried running the code on a real device instead of the Simulator to see if the same logs appear?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, schedule a snapshot in your `handle(_ )` method somewhere. Preferably when task is completed or when you have something to show.

```
WKExtension.shared().scheduleSnapshotRefresh(withPreferredDate: fireDate, userInfo: nil) { error in
        if (error == nil) {
            print("successfully scheduled snapshot.  All background work completed.")
        }
    }
```